# rewrite rule to stat with question mark?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is is bothering me for while and I have tried many rules but never could make it work as I expected.

so the dynamic URL is https://URL/index.php?type=filesextension

and I am attempting to make it https://URL/?fileextension

the best I can get is https://URL/?type=fileextension , I can't remove "type=" in the middle of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use regex for that.. use capture groups and gather it in the destination. something like `^https:\/\/(.*\/).*=(.*)$` goes to `https://$1?$2` - obviously, it should be written better than this.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/q6RSwu/1 something like that